# How to monitor training process in tf.estimator.Estimator like Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am porting a Keras model into `Estimator` using `tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator()`. However, I could not figure out how to monitor training process (progress bar) like in Keras when I call `estimator.train()`

Code

```
# define a Keras model
model   = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
model.compile(...)

# Convert into Estimator object
estimator = tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator(keras_model=model,
                                                  model_dir='./logs')

# **PROBLEM HERE** I could not monitor the training process here
estimator.train(input_fn=lambda: create_tfdata(data.train.images,
                                               data.train.labels,
                                               num_epochs=epochs,
                                               shuffle=True,
                                               batch_size=batch_size),
                max_steps=steps_per_epoch)
```

If I call `model.fit()`, it will show the progress bar like this:

```
Epoch 1/5
469/469 [==============================] - 116s 248ms/step - loss: 0.1870 - acc: 0.9433
Epoch 2/5
 67/469 [===>..........................] - ETA: 1:20 - loss: 0.0613 - acc: 0.9813
```